# How is the CPU initialized by clock ticks?

Tags: boot

> When the computer's power is first turned on, the CPU initializes itself, which is triggered by a series of clock ticks generated by the system clock.

source: http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/BootProcess.asp

I don't get this. Could someone kindly help me understand this?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: maybe [How Computers Boot Up](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/) explains it better?

Comment: @ DavidPostill: How is the CPU initialized by clock ticks? What exactly do they mean by "series of clock ticks generated by the system clock" I am completely lost here.

Comment: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/2/

Comment: At the most basic level, the system clock handles all synchronization within a computer system. The system clock is an electrical signal on the control bus which alternates between zero and one at a periodic rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What happens between Power On and the CPU initializing?

> Hardware Power Sequences: The Pre-Pre-Boot
>
> When someone pushes the power button, the CPU can't simply jump up and
>   start fetching code from flash memory. When external power is first
>   applied, the hardware platform must carry out a number of tasks before
>   the processor can be brought out of its reset state.
>
> The first task is for the power supply to be allowed to settle down to
>   its nominal state. Once the primary power supply settles, there are
>   usually a number of derived voltage levels needed on the platform. For
>   example, on the Intel Architecture reference platform the main input
>   supply is a 12-volt source, but the platform and processor require
>   voltage rails of 1.5, 3.3, 5, and 12 volts. Voltages must be provided
>   in a particular order, a process known as power sequencing. The power
>   is sequenced by controlling analog switches, typically field-effect
>   transistors. The sequence is often driven by a Complex Program Logic
>   Device (CPLD).
>
> Platform clocks are derived from a small number of input clock and
>   oscillator sources. The devices use phase-locked loop circuitry to
>   generate the derived clocks used for the platform. These clocks take
>   time to converge.
>
> It is only after all these steps have occurred that the
>   power-sequencing CPLD can de-assert the reset line to the processor,
>   as illustrated in Figure 1. Depending on integration of silicon
>   features, some of this logic may be on chip and controlled by
>   microcontroller firmware that starts prior to the main processor.
>
> [image]
>
> Once the processor reset line has been de-asserted, the processor
>   begins fetching instructions.

Source [Booting an Intel Architecture System, Part I: Early Initialization](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/booting-an-intel-architecture-system-par/232300699)

---

#### What is the clock signal?

> So, what is clock anyway? Clock is a signal used to sync things inside
>   the computer. Take a look at Figure 2, where we show a typical clock
>   signal: it is a square wave changing from “0” to “1” at a fixed rate.
>   On this figure you can see three full clock cycles (“ticks”). The
>   beginning of each cycle is when the clock signal goes from “0” to “1”;
>   we marked this with an arrow. The clock signal is measured in a unit
>   called Hertz (Hz), which is the number of clock cycles per second. A
>   clock of 100 MHz means that in one second there is 100 million clock
>   cycles.
>
> [image]
>
> In the computer, all timings are measured in terms of clock cycles.

Source [Clock](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/2/)

---

#### Further reading

- [How a CPU Works](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/)

Comment: `a RAM memory with a “5” latency means that it will delay five full clock cycles to start delivering data` What a poor way of describing the process; it sounds like the memory waits for the 5 clock cycles and then instantly have the data available. You should have pointed out that it takes 5 clock cycles for the memory to process the address, fetch the data, and set the voltages on the data bus.

Comment: @LDC3 Ambiguous text removed from quotation.

Comment: If clock ticks are an idea then how can something without tangible existence startup the cpu? At the verge of giving it up, maybe Computer science is not for me.

Comment: @MarkHennery Clock ticks are not an idea - they are generated by some electronics on the motherboard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_generator

Comment: @MarkHennery Read my answer again. When the power is on and the clock circuits are synchronized then the Power Sequencing and Control Device sends a reset signal to the CPU. This causes the CPU to start doing it's thing (initialising).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You've helped me as much as you could. Computer hardware is coming in  hard for me. I am a coder(self-taught). I was able to teach my self programming which is considered hard yet computer hardware  is coming in super hard for me! Maybe I am old now?(29 years old now, learned how to code when I was in my late teen years).

Comment: @MarkHennery Hehe, I'm 50+ and still learning ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill: That's awesome, buddy ;)