# What is purpose of clock in CPU

Tags: memory, cpu, x86

What is the function of the clock signal. I think that when Clock Signal arrives it tells the CPU to make next step (Because each instruction is processed in sequence of microistruction) Example: There is ADD instruction and CPU needs to load first number to register, when clock signal arrives it set WRITE wire so the register will be ready to recieve data, when second clock signal arrives cpu set Write wire onto Ram and send adress to the Memory Controller Hub, when data arrives it has to disable WRITE wire. These 3 microinstructions couldn`t be processed in same time, because the register WRITE wire will be disabled before the data arrives so that will lead that instruction wouldn't be processed correctly. So for me it looks like this: Cpu microcode tells CPU to do something and then wait for the next clock signal make next step... I don't know if I am right?

So the questions are:

1. How will CPU know when to make next step?
2. How will CPU know that required data from RAM arrived?
3. If is true that every stage in pipeline need 1 clock cycle, what CPU will do      when it is waiting for data from RAM

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: See my answers [How is the CPU initialized by clock ticks?](http://superuser.com/a/936351) and [How are clock rate measured and what does it mean?](http://superuser.com/a/964541)?s=2|2.1401#964541

Comment: [How a CPU Works](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/)

Comment: If this is homework you need to learn how to research.

Comment: It isn`t homework, I just want to know how it work at the lowest level

Comment: @DavidPostill I have read both answers, but there is just that it is used to sync things inside computers, but nothing about what does it REALLY mean for CPU

Comment: @PcAF The answer you're looking for is far too big for this forum. Go read a book on the subject or google some more.  I have provided you with two references in my answer to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

> Most integrated circuits (ICs) of sufficient complexity use a clock signal in order to synchronize different parts of the circuit.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_signal

The above is a good start. If you want to know more, don't ask here -- go find a decent electronics book.

I also see plenty of [online learning material](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig51.php) on the web. Some of it looks very good. Just google for `electronics clock signal`.

Comment: Thanks. I found something on there: http://www.ehow.com/info_12274931_function-clock-signal-digital-electronics.html, just under the subtitle "Event Trigger"

Comment: Also, I am asking here because I have found many informations about this , I could identify that some of them are false (clock frequency means how many instruction can processor process), so i wanted to know how others members react for answer. Sorry if it shouldn`t be there.